# Phonegap android exit app not working

Tags: android, cordova, exit

Using phonegap 2.5.0 but the exit app always gives object has no method exitApp

used `navigator.device.exitApp()`

Is this depreciated? or am I just using it wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `navigator.app.exitApp();`

Comment: thanks could not find that in the documents or missed it XD guess was using depreciated exit app

Answer (score 4):

You can use this condition

```
 if (navigator.app) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else if (navigator.device) {
            navigator.device.exitApp();
        }
```

this works fine. No version Problem.

Comment: @abraham Petit- what type of error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

you could use BackButton.exitApp();